# PHP Unit not working on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with PHP5.6

Tags: php, phpunit, ubuntu-12.04, pear, php-code-coverage

Any one can help me to solve my problem. I want to run phpunit on php5.6 but got the issue

```
:~$ phpunit
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 38
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/bin/phpunit on line 38
```

Pear Packed installed

## Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:

Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.4.0   stable
Benchmark        1.2.9   stable
Console_Getopt   1.4.1   stable
PEAR             1.10.1  stable
PEAR_Manpages    1.10.0  stable
PHPUnit          1.3.2   stable
Structures_Graph 1.1.1   stable
XML_Util         1.3.0   stable

For Install PHPUnit i did run the below command on terminal

```
:~$ sudo pear install pear/PHPUnit
```

because of `:~$ sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit` not working.

I did try to add `:~$ pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de` but it's showing the error

```
Error: No version number found in <channel> tag
Discovering channel pear.phpunit.de over http:// failed with message: channel-add: invalid channel.xml file
Trying to discover channel pear.phpunit.de over https:// instead
Error: No version number found in <channel> tag
Discovery of channel "pear.phpunit.de" failed (channel-add: invalid channel.xml file)
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved to install  For PHPUnit 5.7 use `https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-5.7.phar` instead of `https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar`. If you continue to use

Answer (score 1):

[PHPUnit cannot be installed via the PEAR Installer anymore](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method).

Have a look at this "[Getting Started](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html)" how-to and learn how to install PHPUnit using PHAR or Composer.

Comment: I did try it. it's not working. it's showing same error